# Link selectable from middle

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I make a link selectable, like normal text, without triggering the mouse click?

Unlinked text can be easily selected from the middle. I want to make the link selectable if the user holds down the mouse, but if it's a single click then open the link as normal.

Comment: Can you please include and example of what you need ? your question is a little difficult to understand

Comment: for example any of link on any page if u try to select the link text from middle it will be not selectable ... link can only be selected from the ending points but not from the middle ... but i want the link to be selected just like simple text.

Comment: I definitely understand what you want, but can you explain your use case? In other words, why?

Comment: Maybe you could use say a `<span>` controlled with JS instead of a `<a>`. That would avoid the default anchor behavior.

Comment: its just the case that i want to select the link text ... some thing like twitter that the tweet text is use to be clickable link but also selectable.

Comment: @James below has a great answer. Check this too. http://www.screenr.com/dIos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is defined by the browser so there's not much you can do about it. I believe some browsers do allow you to select anchor text from any point (Opera?), not just the start and end, but that's not much use to you.

***If you really want to change the default browser behaviour (which is rarely a good idea), then read on...***

One potential solution could be to not use `a` elements, but instead use something like `span`. Give each `span` link a common class and store the intended URL:

```
<span class="linkSpan" data-link="http://www.example.com">This is a link</span>
```

Then use JavaScript (you've tagged the question with jQuery so I'll use jQuery here) to redirect the user:

```
$(".linkSpan").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).data("link");
});
```

Obviously you would need to style `.linkSpan` appropriately to make it appear more like an actual link.

**Update** (following @Madmartigan's comment) - if you hold the mouse button down when the cursor is not over the link, then move over the link itself, you can start selecting text from any point within the link. I managed that in Chrome at least.

Comment: @Gull That's the good answer. You shouldn't be able to avoid the default behavior by keeping anchors.

Comment: I was just able to select the text in Glide's user name link with a little ninjutsu mouse movement (FF9), so if your users are savvy enough they should be able to figure it out. I wonder *why* you'd need to offer this to non-tech-savvy users to begin with? Do users copy link text at all, and from the middle for some reason?

Comment: @Glide yes this is very good answer and this is going to help me to get the problem fix ... Madmatigan thanks for the ninjustu but not possible to give ninja classes to the users ... thanks every body

Comment: @Gull: I'm still very interested in your use case for this if you could spare a moment to briefly explain it. 99% of the time, deviating from normal browser behavior only confuses normal users, so I'm wondering why you want to implement this. Besides, James's solution doesn't seem to behave differently than a normal link in that respect: http://jsfiddle.net/TaCDC/

Comment: Sorry if this sounds rude, but this is a non-working solution to a non-existent problem. More importantly, delegating link behavior to javascript like this and marking up links as spans is an awful idea. This needs a warning of that sort or it just sets a bad example.

Comment: @Madmartigan - I agree that there's not really a problem, but this *is* a solution to what the OP has asked. I would never use something like this without good reason. However, I don't think a -1 is justified as this does actually answer the question (apologies if the -1 wasn't you).

Comment: Did you test the solution? It certainly doesn't work on my end. Yes, it was my -1. Although you have answered the question, I think you have done so with a *very* bad solution, for reality's sake. If you care to add a disclaimer I don't mind removing the DV, but otherwise it stays. This is exactly the kind of thing some noob will copy/paste, ask another question about here, and get berated (rightfully so) for using spans as links.

Comment: @Madmartigan - Yes, I tested it in Chrome 16 and it works. I agree it's not a great solution, but is there another solution? I also agree that it's never a good idea to change default browser behaviour, and wouldn't implement this myself, but for all we know the OP has a very good reason.

Comment: You're saying you can highlight part of the text without triggering the click event? Does not work for me in Chrome 16, it still fires the click event: http://jsfiddle.net/TaCDC/1/ However, it *does* allow the selection before going to the next page, so I see your angle now. DV removed - sorry, this just goes against all that is holy.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. I didn't notice that because I think I was selecting from the middle to beyond the end. If the cursor has left the `span` when you release the button, the `click` event does not fire. It could be worked around by handling `mouseUp` and `mouseDown`.

Comment: I posted another solution that avoids the pitfalls of this one. Same idea, so the results are no better, but at least it's unobtrusive.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to do this, don't butcher your HTML with `<span>`s posing as links. You're using javascript, so just use javascript to remove the `href` from the links and attach it's value to the `onclick` event.

Something like this (using jQuery):

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).removeAttr('href'); // Now the link is "more selectable"
    $(this).click(function(){
        top.location = href;
    });
});
```

Much more accessible, doesn't force you to write bogus HTML. Links should be marked up with the `<a>` tag. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/phbt4/1/

You'll have to specify styles on these links to make sure they look/feel like links instead of rely on browser defaults, as removing the `href` attribute will have this affect.

Comment: Thanks James. As a true HTML purist/snob, I hate to see hacky stuff like span-anchors hardcoded into markup when it could be easily applied with javascript.

Comment: a perfect solution as compare to the previous one.

Comment: this solution has a little problem selecting any sub part of the link do works but also invoke triger the click and resulted in page load.

Comment: @Gull: Yeah it's not perfect, just an alternative to the `<span>` trick with identical behavior. See our string of comments on James's answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if OP explained his reason for needing this, we could provide a more sensible alternative.